# Images mess up my table layout

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

Here is the test file: http://www.nicoeinsidler.bplaced.net/test/mail_test.html

If there are no pictures everything works fine as expected, but as soon as I add picture to it they break my layout.

```
<img src="https://img.skitch.com/20110930-e89yb812kuhisgsuhf896aepnx.png" alt="http://www.nicoeinsidler.bplaced.net/test/mail_test.html" />
```

(I never layout my homepages with tables, so I'm not good at it. I have to do it because this will become a HTML-Email…)

Here is how it should look like:

[image: Bildschirmfoto 2011-09-29 um 20.46.53]

Comment: what should be the expected layout ?

Comment: Can you explain how you want it to look, or add a screenshot with a mockup of how you want it to look?  Also, obligatory comment about not using tables for layout =)

Comment: 1) yep. Sorry. I added it. 2) because Hotmail ignores every positioning and margins (!!!)

Comment: Don't feel bad for using tables NE555, any major email provider will tell you it's the only sure fire way to get a relatively decent layout with HTML email. It's still painful to have to do though.

Comment: @Blake and NE555 - Sorry, just joking about the tables.  I do recognize the necessity in situations like this =)

Comment: Thanks! :) I hope that will change pin future. I hate tables for layout!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The td inside the following tr needs to have a colspan of 3 (instead of 2)

(You should see the broken border in that row)

Comment: thanks! but how should I change the height? css is not working here… and html's width="" also not...